# Can an arbitrary metric space be made into a complete and separable metric space?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Can any metric space be made into a separable and complete metric space by suitably choosing an isometry?

Answer (score 3):

Separability is a topological (hence isometric) invariant. Completeness is an isometric invariant. So the answer is: "Never, unless it was complete and/or separable to begin with".

Moreover, since subspaces of a separable metric space are separable metric spaces, a metric space which is not separable can never be isometrically embedded into a separable metric space.

On the other hand, a metric space can always be isometrically *embedded* into a complete metric space with some nice properties, called its "[metric completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion)".